What makes philosophy philosophy? Can all of Plato's dialogues be considered philosophical?
Dialogues that contain something like an objective argument, like the Republic, or the Parmenides, would be philosophy in the sense we understand it today, but what about the Timaeus, or even the Symposium?  The one is a set of myths, and the other a combination of myths, odes, and beliefs.  Does Socrates give us an argument for his concept of love or merely a speech telling us what he believes?
Thales and Anaximenes gave material and rational-like accounts for being, water and air, but the apeiron?  That honestly sounds mystical to me, as do the fragments of Heraclitus.  Don't even get me started on Pythagoras.  Empedocles?  A metaphysics based on love and hate?  What makes all these crazy ideas philosophical?  What legitimately ties them together under that rubric other than tradition?

Presocratic philosophy is still considered relevant for the evolution of Western philosophy and Plato is considered by many THE philosopher. See Alfred North Whitehead's well-known remark that “the safest general characterization of the European philosophical tradition is that it consists in a series of footnotes to Plato".

@Gerry It is refreshing to ponder your question: Which thoughts from the history of philosophy stand in high esteem today only because they have a long tradition? - What about the concept of progress, not only in science but also in philosophy?

Philosophy is about reflection and wisdom, those do not have to come in the form of "objective arguments" only. And there is a lot more to Timaeus than myths, it inspired an entire philosophical tradition of neo-Platonism. You should read up on it, see SEP.

I realize that the Presocratics are relevant to philosophy, but that doesn't necessarily make them philosophers.  After all, the development of Christianity is relevant to philosophy, but we don't consider the new testament to be a work of philosophy.  Darwin is relevant to modern philosophy, and yet we don't consider Darwin to be a philosopher., etc.

Also, I'm well aware that Plato is considered the epitome of philosophy, but my question is why is that the case.  Your answer suggests that he is a philosopher because authority  or tradition tells us so.  I'm less cynical and think there's a better answer.  Jo suggests that they may not be strictly speaking philosophers in the modern sense, but are at least proto philosophers, in which case, there has to be some connection between proto and  modern philosophy that allows us to label them all as philosophy.
